# How do I compare nested multi-level models using anova(), with REML?

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model, lme4-nlme

I am trying to compare two nested multilevel models using the `anova()` function in R. I am specifying the models in the `lme4` package. Since I am testing the addition of a random effect, I want to use REML to estimate the models. However, when I go to compare them using the `anova()` function, I get the following error:

```
refitting model(s) with ML (instead of REML)
```

For example:

```
mod4.reml <- lmer(stress~1+age+gender+experien+ # L1 #
              expcon+ # L2 #
              hospsize+ # L3 #
             (1|wardid)+(1|hospital), data=data, REML=TRUE)

mod5 <- lmer(stress~1+age+gender+experien+ # L1 #
         expcon+ # L2 #
         hospsize+ # L3 #
        (1|wardid)+(1+expcon|hospital), data=data, REML=TRUE)

anova5 <- anova(mod4.reml,mod5)
```

Gives me:

```
refitting model(s) with ML (instead of REML)
```

How can I compare these two models using REML?

Comment: I think that anova does a likelihood ratio test.  The thinh with REML is that it ''transforms'' the likelihood to make it independent of the mean.  So when using REML you should be very carefull with likelihood ratio tests. But if you realy want to use REML, then you can do the likelihood ratio test yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I would post the answer myself, in case anyone in the future is wondering the same thing. You specify `refit=FALSE` in the `anova` function:

```
anova5 <- anova(mod0, mod1, refit=FALSE)
```